# ¿Porque estos span ignora mi css?

Tags: java, html, css, eclipse

vengo con una pregunta mas compleja de lo que el titulo originalmente da a pensar. Estoy intentando arreglar una barra de herramientas de mi aplicación, esta debería mostrar sus opciones y cada opción muestra un desplegable.

Hasta ahí fácil, el problema viene que la barra no me muestra los nombres de las acciones, hace bien su trabajo, funcionan, muestran el desplegable (con texto correcto y funcionando) pero las opciones principales no las muestra, estas están dentro de varios span.

Objetivo: Que me muestre el texto, no necesariamente como span pero priorizado

Problemas:

-Estoy usando un css comprado y no se puede tocar, el css aplica la propiedad display:none; sobre los spans por alguna razón, no puedo borrar esa propiedad, desactivandola desde el inspeccionar elemento arregla el problema pero ya digo que manualmente no puedo tocarlo en el archivo.

-No puedo tocar el html y aplicarle un ID a los spans

-Solo tengo acceso a la lista que contiene los span, he probado a crear una clase css para ella y que lo hereden los span que tiene dentro, por alguna razón la ignora por completo

He probado a crear esto:

```
ejemplo 1

.spanTablaMaestras{
    display:block !important;
}

ejemplo 2

.spanTablaMaestras > a > span{
    display:block !important;
}
```

en el css, pero como digo no me lo pilla cuando añado la styleClass o la class a seca sobre la lista.

También he intentado

```
span::before{

    font-weight: bold;
    color: navy;
    content: "Prueba ";
}
```

pero nada, no afecta a los span.....
Como nota a parte, el proyecto es responsive y aunque inicialmente el menú y la barra están ocultos existe un botón para desplegarla y muestra los spans bien, en un primer lugar pensé que el display none lo heredaba de ese estilo por error, pero mirándolo en responsive, esa linea desaparece, no afecta al modo responsive y solo está presente en la versión normal

TODAS las ideas bienvenidas

EDIT: Encontré la solución. Consistía en borrar la linea en 2 css independientes. Muchas gracias a todos los que habeis intentado ayudar.

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir el código HTML generado de la parte que contiene los span? También el código CSS que tiene el `display:none`. Eso sería de gran ayuda para ver por qué tu CSS no está funcionando correctamente.

Comment: Por favor, haz lo que te solicita @AlvaroMontoro ya que sin el HTML no podemos comprobar si ese CSS encaja con el HTML que usas. Debes entender que el operador `>` significa "descendiente directo", por lo que si hay otra etiqueta intermedia no surtirá efecto.

Comment: ¿Podrías redactar una respuesta con la solución que has adoptado y marcarla como correcta? Además, si compartes el HTML como te dijimos, podríamos sugerirte alguna forma mejor de configurar el selector (que sospecho que es el culpable de que no te funcione).

Answer (score 1):

A mí me pasó algo similar hace tiempo y aunque puede ser complejo de solucionar en algunos casos, a mí me vino bien usar JavaScript para pisar los estilos externos que no me interesaban.

La forma que me parece más sencilla de solucionarlo con JS es la siguiente:

```
//Llamar al elemento dentro del DOM
var elemento = document.querySelector('.claseDelElemento');

//Pisar las propiedades del style con setAtribute() 
elemento.setAttribute("style", "display:block;");
```

El inconveniente de esto es que no sólo cambia la propiedad display de ese elemento, sino que elimina el resto de estilos que tenga. Si no tiene más o no son importantes realmente, no habría problema. Pero si hay algun estilo del span que te interese en concreto, puedes añadirlo desde JS también con ese mismo método.

Habría que tener en cuenta que es posible que en la vista responsive aparezcan siempre los spans ya que se han pisado completamente sus estilos, pero se podría solucionar con un mediaquery.

Hay otras opciones un poco más complejas por si esta no funciona. Todo es ir probando. Te dejo un enlace que lo explica:
https://norfipc.com/inf/javascript-como-cambiar-modificar-estilo-css-paginas-web.html

Comment: Has matado moscas a cañonazos. Ya que haces uso de javascript, deberías saber que puedes usar `elemento.style.display = "block";` para no modificar el resto de estilos. Por otro lado, ese selector de clase fallará igualmente para el OP si es erróneo, ya que está usando el operador de descendiente directo (`>`) cuando quizá su elemento no lo sea.